# Add related data to cross reference table in Entity Framework 5 (Code-First)

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-5, code-first, cross-reference

Let's say I have the following two models:

```
Person             N
Subscription       N
```

They are in a many-to-many relationship (Each Person can have multiple Subscriptions, and each Subscription can have multiple Persons), so Entity Framework creates a cross reference table:

```
PersonSubscriptions:  PersonId  |  SubscriptionId
```

If I wanted to record *when* each person started subscribing, it would make the most sense to have a Date column in the cross reference table:

```
PersonSubscriptions:  PersonId  |  SubscriptionId  |  SubscribedOn
```

How can I achieve this with Entity Framework and how would I query, say, to get all Persons that subscribed after day X to a given Subscription?

Answer (score 3):

sIn this situation, you no longer have a many-to-many relationship in a traditional sense, you instead have 2 distinct 1 to many relationships with a 3rd entity.  In essence, you will have 3 classes to work with:

```
Public Class Person {
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public virtual IEnumerable<SubscriptionInfo> SubscriptionInfos {get;set;}
}

Public Class Subscription {
    public int SubscriptionId {get;set;}
    public virtual IEnumberable<SubscriptionInfo> SubscriptionInfos {get;set}
}

Public Class SubscriptionInfo {
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public int SubscriptionId {get;set;}
    public DateTime SubscribedOn {get;set;}

    [RelatedTo(ForeignKey="PersonId")]
    Public virtual Person Person {get;set;}

    [RelatedTo(ForeignKey="SubscriptionId")]
    Public virtual Subscription Subscription {get;set;}
}

var db = new PeopleSubscribedEntities();
var subscription = db.Subscriptions.Find(1);
var people = subscription.SubscriptionInfos.Select(si => si.Person 
                                                  && si => si.SubscribedOn > someDate);
```

If Entity Framework were to treat this table as a many to many, you would lose the extra attributes.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! Would you expect your sample code to create the table as I outlined in my question? Or a separate SubscriptionInfo table?

Comment: I just referred to it as SubscriptionInfo in my samples, but if it were named PersonSubscriptions, it would create a table named that, with the 3 fields... I was mostly offering a direction to take the code, but the names can be changed, of course.  With the class names I used, Entity Framework would create a SubscriptionInfo table instead of the default join table.